# Jenkins: keep only the last file in a directory

Tags: jenkins

I  need a job in Jenkins that every time is running keeps only the last file created in a folder and discard all the older ones.
I'm not sure how to do it. 
Any suggestion welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `execute shell` step after your build step. And read [this post](https://superuser.com/a/554512/652923). It will delete other than 10 latest files. In your case which is 1 file. So modified code looks like

```
cd <PATH HERE TO YOUR FOLDER>
ls -1tr | head -n -1 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

I think you have `xargs` installed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the fact that every time jenkins job run, it clears out the workspace. So in order to keep the last file created you might want to copy file to a different location on the jenkins box apart from **/workspace** directory and later restore it under the same directory. You can overwrite the file every time.

You can achieve this with a pre/post execute shell script in the jenkins job.